# C# sequence unhandled exception

Tags: c#, sequence

```
//1. add 10 numbers in sequence , print only steam numbers.

int[] seq= new int[10];
int n = 0;
int[] seq2= new int[n];

for (int i = 0; i < seq.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Add number ");
    seq[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (seq[i]%2==0)
    {
        seq2[n] = seq[i];
        n++;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < seq2.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(seq2[i]);
}
```

There is something wrong with sequence2 and the program isn't telling anything about it , can someone help ? it's not about the task i did it other way but i just want to understand what did i do wrong here .

Comment: Please elaborate on 'there's something wrong'. *What* is wrong with it? What is it doing? What *should* it be doing?

Comment: Hehe if i knew what is wrong with it i wouldn't been asking for help here :P , but i get your point . Tnx for advice :P

Comment: I don't mean 'what needs to be fixed', I mean 'what is your definition of wrong?'. You've told us you think it's wrong, but not *why* you think so. If you get an error, you should show the error message and the line it occurred on

Comment: I sad it in question title unhandled exception (that's what program printed when crashed)  , when i sad program isn't telling anything i meant that he didn't show me typing errors but still can't run code smoothly . But yea i could've sad more about it ...will do it in future but its hard not to make a mile long question ,was trying to make it simple .

Comment: Your `seq2` is always zero length... because you started with `n` is 0. I bet you are getting index out of range exception...

Comment: Yes i do get index out of range expection , but i place n++ in for loop , shouldn't it increase the length of seq2 every time user adds steam number in seq1 ?

Comment: I even tried adding seq2 = new int[n]; to loop but still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared `Seq2` array with length `0` in below shown part of your code. So it will always fail with **Index was outside the bounds of the array** exception when you do this `seq2[n] = seq[i];`.

```
int n = 0;
int[] seq2= new int[n];
```

Declare `Seq2` as list instead. Like this..

```
var seq2= new List<int>();
```

and then do this..

```
seq2.Add(seq[i]);
```

Your **final code will look like this**..

```
int[] seq= new int[10];
var seq2= new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < seq.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Add number ");
    seq[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (seq[i]%2==0)
    {
        seq2.Add(seq[i]);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < seq2.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(seq2[i]);
}
```

Comment: Not to mention that using the size of an array to index into it will also always result in "Index was outside the bounds of the array" since the last index is always size-1

Comment: Tnx ,didn't know list exist , i'm still beginner

Comment: what does var stands for ? I see it first time .

Comment: @АлексаЈевтић : var is implicit typing. type of the variable is determined by Right hand side expression.  `List<int> seq2= new List<int>();` does the same.

Comment: what else can be on right side of var variable ? :P tried int but it doesn't let me xD

Comment: @АлексаЈевтић : `var sampleInt = 1;` this is how you do for int.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know the number of elements in the second array, and C# doesn't have dynamic arrays (I think), just use a list instead:

```
int[] seq= new int[10];
int n = 0;
List<int> seq2= new List<int>;

for (int i = 0; i < seq.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Add number ");
    seq[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (seq[i]%2==0)
    {
        seq2.Add(seq[i]);
        n++;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < seq2.Length - 1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(seq2[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the arrays obligatory?

```
int n = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Add number ");
    int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (a%2==0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

If they are, you will need a List because you don't know how many of them will be even.

Edit: just read the bottom line..